# Exporting SharePoint lists to access database

Tags: reports, microsoft-access

I am getting an error message saying I do not have the correct permissions to link a view from my sharepoint site to microsoft access to produce a report (I am the administrator with full control). How do I change the permissions to let me do this? Is it referring to the access or sharepoint permissions?

Comment: Version (SP and Access)? Authentication model (FBA, Windows, Claims, Classic)?

Comment: Does your list have content approval turned on? I have run into issues while using that feature.